# How to stop GCP vm instances using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, infrastructure

How to stop GCP vm instances using terraform? I have tried changing status of the vm instance, it's available for AWS but couldn't find the way to do it for GCP.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently available using the google provider:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1719